# Find directories that doesn't contain "*.sql" files

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have several directories like below. I want to list the directories which dont have the SQL files. For example "dev.mysite.com" in below example. Im using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
orange.com/
    orange.com.sql
    10.10.10.1/public_html/...

apple.edu.us/
    apple.edu.sql
    10.10.10.2/public_html/...

dev.mysite.com/
    10.10.10.3/public_html/

example.com/
    mysql_dbdump20150911.sql
    10.10.11.11/public_html/...
```

Ive tried to achieve this using "find" with "cut" and "xargs" and moving those directories to the "dirwithsql" directory and take remaining ones as directory without sql file manually.

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -iname "*.sql" | cut -d'/' -f 2 | xargs -n 1 -I {} mv {} /backup/dirwithsql/{}
```

Ive tried with

```
find -maxdepth 2 ! -iname "*.sql" -exec dirname {} \;
```

But above command shows all directories

Is there any better method ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently, this worked for me

```
for f in $(find . -type d -maxdepth 2); do if [[ $(ls -1 $f | grep '.sql$'|wc -l) == 0 ]] ; then echo $f; fi; done
```

Comment: Thanks man :) it works but i need to get some grip on these expressions

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' n; do [ -f "$n"/*.sql ] || echo $n; done
```

Shall work even with exotic directory names (spaces, newlines...)